# Delete folder collections using command prompt (.bat file)

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have folder **APK** into APK different included as: `framework-res`, `MyFiles`, `SystemUI`, `twframework-res`, etc.

```
APK\framework-res\res\values-in
APK\framework-res\res\values-vi
APK\framework-res\res\values 
APK\framework-res\res\values-ko
APK\framework-res\res\values-it 
APK\framework-res\res\values-vi-rVN

...

APK\MyFiles\res\values-in
APK\MyFiles\res\values-vi
APK\MyFiles\res\values
APK\MyFiles\res\values-ko
APK\MyFiles\res\values-it
APK\MyFiles\res\values-vi-rVN

...

APK\SystemUI\res\values-in
APK\SystemUI\res\values-vi
APK\SystemUI\res\values
APK\SystemUI\res\values-ko
APK\SystemUI\res\values-it
APK\SystemUI\res\values-vi-rVN

...

APK\twframework-res\res\values-in
APK\twframework-res\res\values-vi
APK\twframework-res\res\values
APK\twframework-res\res\values-ko
APK\twframework-res\res\values-it
APK\twframework-res\res\values-vi-rVN

...
```

I want to try delete these folders `values-vi-rVN`; `values-vi`; `values-in`; `values-it` for all paths from the command prompt in Windows:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ('dir .\apk /ad/b') do rd APK\%%a\res\values-v* /s/q
for %%a in ('dir .\apk /ad/b') do rd APK\%%a\res\values-i* /s/q
pause
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give FOR the /F switch to use a command inside the parenthesis.

```
for /F %%a in ('dir .\apk /ad/b') do rd APK\%%a\res\values-v* /s/q
    ^^
```

try C:>help for

Answer (score 0):

Test results @Keith:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Press any key to continue . . . –